# "Duplicate symbols" linker error for no apparent reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I am seeing `Duplicate symbols` when linking my project. I have no idea what this means, nor how to fix it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

since shipNameText seems to be the source of the error, here is where I use it: 
in .h:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet  UILabel *shipNameText;
```

in .m

```
@interface boatInfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation boatInfoViewController
@synthesize shipNameText, shipSizeText;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *shipName = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSUserDefaults *shipSize = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                 objectForKey:@"shipName"];
    NSString *size = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                      objectForKey:@"shipSize"];
    shipNameText.text = name;
    shipSizeText.text = size;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to clean the build folder

Comment: Check if you have #import'ed an .m file instead of the .h file somewhere. - Perhaps `#import "boatInfoViewController.m"`?

Comment: got me there! darn you xcode auto finish :p

Comment: OK. Do you want a formal answer that you can accept?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Rep for the both of us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens if you import the implementation file "boatInfoViewController.m" instead of the interface file "boatInfoViewController.h", because "boatInfoViewController.m" is then compiled twice.

Comment: Note that the class should be capitalized;  `BoatInfoViewController`.

Comment: Does it make any difference, or just for looks? @bbum

Comment: That is for coding conventions. Class names should start with an upper case. Check this [Coding guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH)

Comment: What ACB said;  coding conventions.  If you follow them, your code will be more like the sample code, the framework APIs, and other developers will be able to more easily grok your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have got an ivar declared twice. Its name is `shipNameText` and it is declared in `boatInfoViewController` and somewhere else. Do you use 'local' ivars by simply declaring somewhere between `@implementation` and `@end`?

Comment: Added code to question on where I use them. See anything wrong?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with your code, now that the code is visible. As Martin said, you included the .m file somewhere instead of the .h file. However, you get pretty similar error messages from the linker when you just define local ivars in the implementation and use the same name in two or more classes.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I got the similar linker error because of declaring my variables outside the @ interface and @ end inside my .h file. I resolved it by putting it between @ interface and @ end. Why is it so? I don't understand..

Comment: @Cherry_thia, underneath Objective-C there is C. If you declare it wthin `@interface` or `@implementation` and `@end` then the Objective C takes care about them The variable is then considered a class cariable or instance variable of the object/class. Everyting outside thes `@`-directives is plain C. 
In plan C a variable declared outside a function block (or any block) is global per definition. Within C that works fine if all other modules, that are compiled separately and linked together, use the same variable name with an #external directive. In Obj-C we usually don't do it that way.